# Relationship Between Stream Function and Velocity Potential

Tags: fluid-dynamics

My understanding is that a velocity potential is a scalar function whose gradient yields the x and y components of a flow's velocity vector. Velocity potential can be graphed, where lines of equivalent velocity potential denote equipotential lines. Equipotential lines, when graphed, resemble contour lines on a map which specifies altitude. Therefore, the gradient of any given equipotential line denotes 'slope', or the x and y components of velocity.

I have heard that the stream function, when graphed, is perpendicular to the velocity function; also, it can only be found for 2-D flows. What is the motivation for having a stream function? What does it represent? And does it relate to the aforementioned picture of velocity potential? If so, how?

Comment: In addition to AJK's answer, the velocity potential and streamfunction can be combined into a complex velocity potential where the real part is the velocity potential and the complex part is the streamfunction. I couldn't find a good reference for this online but _Principles of Ideal Fluid Aerodynamics_ by Karamcheti has a detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

The stream function and the velocity potential are used for two different cases, depending on whether the flow is incompressible or irrotational.

If $\nabla \cdot \bf{v} = 0$, then you can write $\bf{v} = \nabla \times \bf{A}$, where $\bf{A}$ is a vector field (remember $\nabla \cdot (\nabla\times\bf{v}) =0$).  By contrast, if $\nabla \times \bf{v} = 0$, you can write $\bf{v} = \nabla \phi$, where $\phi$ is a scalar velocity potential.  This is true for any reasonable $\bf{v}$, and follows from the Helmholtz decomposition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition

The "stream function" is often given by writing the vector potential in a particular form; if ${\bf A} = (0,0,\psi)$, then the resulting flow will be in 2D.  However, streamfunctions are also useful in 3D cases with axisymmetry.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_stream_function and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_function